# Pandas: Filling a new column in Dataframe where 2 of the other columns match

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I'm having to do calculations on dataframe_one, then create a new column on dataframe_two and fill the results. dataframe_one is multi indexed, while the second one is not but there are columns that are matched to the indices in dataframe_one.

This is what I'm currently doing:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
dataframe_two = {}
dataframe_two['project_id'] = [1, 2]
dataframe_two['scenario'] = ['hgh', 'low']
dataframe_two = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_two)
dataframe_one = {}
dataframe_one['ts_project_id'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
dataframe_one['ts_scenario'] = ['hgh', 'hgh', 'hgh', 'hgh', 'hgh', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']
dataframe_one['ts_economics_atcf'] = [-2, 2, -3, 4, 5 , -6, 3, -3, 4, 5]
dataframe_one = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_one)
dataframe_one.index = [dataframe_one['ts_project_id'], dataframe_one['ts_scenario']]

project_scenario = zip(dataframe_two['project_id'], dataframe_two['scenario'])
dataframe_two['econ_irr'] = np.zeros(len(dataframe_two.index))
i = 0
for project, scenario in project_scenario:
    # Grabs corresponding series from dataframe_one
    atcf = dataframe_one.ix[project].ix[scenario]['ts_economics_atcf']
    irr = np.irr(atcf.values)
    dataframe_two['econ_irr'][i] = irr
    i = i + 1

print dataframe_two
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: Could you give an example from `dataframe_one` and `dataframe_two` (or similar dataframes that express the same problem) and a an example of what you expect the output to be? I'm not sure what you mean by "there are columns that are matched to the indices in dataframe_one."

Comment: Just edited the code to give an idea of how it works.

Comment: please indicate source dataframe (one?, two?) contents and expected result. difficult to know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you want pandas equivalent for SQL group_by and aggregation functions. They are essentialy the same, [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) method of a DataFrame and a [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#aggregation) method of `groupby.SeriesGroupBy` object.

```
>>> dataframe_one['ts_economics_atcf'].groupby(level=[0,1]).aggregate(np.irr)
ts_project_id  ts_scenario
1              hgh            0.544954
2              low            0.138952
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I also need to fill in the column in dataframe_two without the multi-indexing capabilities.